# Failed to send Mail with Javax.mail

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send an email on Windows 8.1 with java 1.8 using javax.mail API but I keep getting an error.

Here is the method I wrote:

```
public void sendAlertMail(String from, String to, String header, String msgBody){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smptHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smptPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls","true");
        Session mailSession;
        if (authenticate) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        }
        else{
            mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
        }
        // uncomment for debugging infos to stdout
        // mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = null;
        try {
            transport = mailSession.getTransport();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        try {
            message.addHeaderLine(header);
            message.setContent(msgBody, "text/plain");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
        }
        try {
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message,
                    message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the error I receive is:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at tapperSolution.mail.MailSender.sendAlertMail(MailSender.java:64)
    at tapperSolution.mail.MailSender.sendAlertMail(MailSender.java:74)
    at tapperSolution.mail.MailSender.main(MailSender.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect\at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2066)
... 12 more
```

I turned off my firewall and anti virus and I tried to set the VM option in my code using:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
```

Also tried to set it in the run command with:

> -Djava.net.preferIPv4stack=true

I was able to send mail using Python, but I want to do it using Java.

Tried to capture traffic using Wireshark, but there is no even a TCP handshake with the server.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true? Did u set that flag?

Comment: try to connect to email using telnet outside of your application and see what happens. If you can connect then it is your app permissions that need looking at rather than firewall issues

Comment: Are you running a standalone application, an applet, a jnlp application or something else?

Comment: I did set mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true.

Comment: Show the code and specify Windows vs Linux environment.  _"java.net.SocketException: Permission denied"_ indicates a local error. Maybe you tried to specify an incorrect local IP address (instead of the default to use "any")

Comment: @JimGarrison I didn't try to specify any IP address. I added the environment and the code to my questions.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm trying to add an alert via mail functionality to existing standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SMTP server may be rejecting your connection, perhaps due to authentication issues.  To test this, try a [manual SMTP session](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/exchange/quick-and-simple-smtp-test-easy-as-1-2-3/) from the same machine, and see what the result is.

Comment: It seems the access is denied locally as there is not traffic to server. I was able to send an email from the same machine to the same server using Python.